# Display Mysql results containing double byte characters

Tags: php

I have the following to display the result of a mysql query.

```
while ($row= mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  // Switch the background colour
    $bg = ($bg=='#eeeeee' ? '#ffffff' : '#eeeeee');
    echo '<tr bgcolor="' . $bg . '">
    <td align="left">' . '<p>' . $row['timestamp']  . '</p>' . '</td>
    <td align="left">' . '<p>' . $row['title']  . '</p>' . '</td>
    <td align="left">' . '<p>' . $row['description'] . '</p>' . '</td>
    </tr>';
 }
```

How to I display double-byte characters sets (non-english)?

I have tried add this to my html head but no luck:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When want to put or get data, be sure you're using proper collocation and encoding.:

```
mysql_query("set names 'UTF8'");
mysql_query("set names 'latin1'");
```

And before sending any kind of output, send `Content-Type` header:

```
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
```

P.S: Please don't use **mysql_**  function. Use either **mysqli** or **PDO**.